# Preserve Image Aspect Ratio in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

**Problem:** Reloaded cached UIImageView in a UICollectionViewCell (during scrolling *or* switching between UICollectionViewController) are not preserving the correct contentMode.

I tried using .sizeToFit() on the UIImageView and resetting .contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit on every load, but that wasn't helping.

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> MyCollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MyCollectionViewCell

    if ( indexPath.item < self.the_array?.count ){

        if ( images_cache[self.the_array![indexPath.item].src!] != nil ){
            // calling this here doesn't work
            cell.myImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
            // calling this here doesn't work either
            cell.myImage.sizeToFit()
            cell.myImage.image = images_cache[self.the_array![indexPath.item].src!]! as UIImage
        }
        else{
            if let url  = NSURL(string: "https:" + (self.the_array![indexPath.item].src)!), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
                let the_image = UIImage( data: data )
                cell.myImage.image = the_image
                images_cache[self.the_array![indexPath.item].src!] = the_image!
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:** Set the .frame of the UIImage based on the size of the cell!

```
cell.myImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell.frame.width, height: cell.frame.height)
```

I put that line where I had .sizeToFit() and / or .contentMode and now it preserves the images correctly.